# Python code shows ?? for showing Arabic alphabetic

Tags: python, python-3.x, arabic

I'm using python and a package called `arabic_reshaper` to show utf-8 based characters (arabic alphabets) and this is my example code:

```
import arabic_reshaper

def reshape_arabic_text(input_text):
    # Reshape the Arabic text
    reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(input_text)
    return reshaped_text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_text = "بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم"
    
    reshaped_text = reshape_arabic_text(input_text)
    
    print("Original Arabic Text:")
    print(input_text)
    
    print("\nReshaped Arabic Text:")
    print(reshaped_text)
```

But it shows this result in the Terminal:

[image]

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: This is a problem with your _terminal_, which is unable to display those characters. Python is able to print them without any problem

Comment: What happens when you `type new1.py` in the terminal? Odds are that the terminal (!!) doesn't understand or can't display these characters, while your program is fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwindows%5D+%5Bpython%5D+terminal+unicode -- this search might help.

Comment: You need to use a terminal font that has those characters. I can't reproduce the problem here in Win11 - both original and reshaped versions display fine in both PowerShell and Command Prompt.

Comment: Note that for a _true_ [mre], all you need is: `print( "بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم")`

Comment: First issue: the font your terminal is using does not support either Arabic characters or Arabic Presentation Form characters. Changing the font may fix part of the problem, assuming, assuming the terminal can rendering complex text. 

Secondly, the terminal also doesn't support bidirectional rendering (ie the strings are displayed backwards). You need to use python-bidi with arabic-reshaper.